# Does Using A Tech Recruiter Significantly Bump Pay?

Tags: salary, recruitment

My hypothesis is that using a recruiter doesn't have a significant difference on pay. However, some older and wiser colleagues on my tech team insist it's in my best interest to use one.

Would an average employee with an average recruiter be more likely to have a higher salary than an average employee without a recruiter?

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more specific to my industry. By 'recruiter' I meant 'tech recruiter'

Comment: what do you mean "tech recruiter" in the UK almost all positions are filled by external agencies

Comment: In the US, I'd guess the majority of positions are filled by applicants finding a job posting, and applying to that posting/company with no interaction with an external agency.

Comment: a recruiter that works for you. They get to know you, what you can do, what you're looking for (position and salary wise). They find it, negotiate for you, and the company usually gets a percent off that first contract I believe. Maybe thats what a head hunter is?

Answer (score 4):

> My hypothesis is that using a recruiter doesn't have a significant
>   difference on pay. However, some older and wiser colleagues on my tech
>   team insist it's in my best interest to use one.

These two opinions are not necessarily exclusive to each other.

Using a recruiter might not land you a job with a significant difference in pay, but it still might be in your best interest to use one.

I believe that once you find the particular position of interest, the hiring company won't care if you came in via a recruiter, or on your own. The budget for the position is established ahead of time without regard for how you arrived.

That said, a good agent can connect you with some positions that might not yet be publicly listed, and can work on your behalf to suggest to the hiring manager that you are "worth it" even if you are a bit above their target budget.

You might wish to do what I did years back when I had been laid off. I spent some time on my own seeking a position without finding what I wanted. So I went to a local agent. He sent me on a few interviews, honed in on exactly what I was looking for, and ended up hooking me up with a terrific company. I don't think I got a significantly higher salary than I expected, but I'm pretty sure I would never have connected with this particular job on my own.

Answer (score 3):

A recruiter has nothing to do with your pay, but has to do with the amount of effort the company is extending to find a job, or if you are working with one the amount of effort they are extending to find you a job.

That being said there is also something to be said that companies that are wealthy enough to hire recruiters likely are able to pay more to their employees as well.  This is the same as saying there are more shark attacks with ice cream consumption...

However, that coincidence is something to consider if you are targeting high pay companies...just note alot of times pay compensates for perks...in that you might be worked to death, but paid enough not to complain about it.  Personally I think it best to match yourself and a company up regardless of whether a recruiter is involved or not.

Comment: Must agree. There's no direct correlation.